# Unable to install / enable SimpleTest

Tags: 8, debugging, testing

When I try to install SimpleTest via Extend > Testing > Install, I get the following error:

> The testing framework requires the sites/simpletest directory to exist
>   and be writable in order to run tests. (Currently using Simpletest
>   site directory version Missing)

I have run `$ sudo chmod -R 777 sites/simpletest` in an attempt at mediating this issue, but to no avail.

I am running Drupal 8.3.5 on Fedora 25.

Thank you.